# Reduce scoreboard value instantly by the value of another score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have a scoreboard objective of damage resisted, and it instantly increases based on damage i take with the resistance eff active.
In short, I need to reduce the value of the player's "h" (health) score by whatever is the player's damage resisted score.

I did this odd thing where I reduced the value of the resisted score by 30 each time and reduced 30 on the health, but I need it to be instant, so if I took 300 damage, the value of my "h" score should drop instantly by 300.
Is there a way for this?
Able to use commands up to the latest snapshot.

Comment: You can just have a scoreboard directly linked with a player's health. I don't think you want this, but just making sure - this isn't what you want right? If it is there's a better way to do it

Comment: sadly no, I'm working on a custom health system for a map so this won't work

Answer (score 1):

Okay so if I understand correctly, you have a scoreboard objective let's call it damageTaken. Each player's score is set to how much damage they take. If this is the case then you should be able to do

`/execute if entity @a[scores={damageTaken=2..}] store success score @s damageTaken run scoreboard players operation @s health -= @s damageTaken`

This works as long as the damageTaken score is greater than 1 (just fix that by making the minimum damage 2 or make it multiples of 10 or something). It's just one command, it works for multiplayer, and it resets itself

-cheers

Comment: This is not multiplayer friendly, it needs to be `/execute as @a` not `/execute if entity @a`